# ideviceinstaller not connecting with network option

Tags: ios, linux, libimobiledevice

the option just outputs the usage of ideviceinstaller but with no error and does nothing.

```
own@penguin:~$ ideviceinstaller --network 172.20.10.3 --install dark.ipa
```

i've been stuck on this for the last couple days, any feedback is greatly appreciated

running x86_64 GNU/Linux penguin 5.10.106-15264

Answer (score 0):

For libimobiledevice to connect to your iDevice, it needs a muxer to basically say what devices are available and where.

The vanilla usbmuxd that is shipped with apt, pacman etc. do NOT support detecting devices over the network, you will have to use alternatives.

[usbmuxd2](https://github.com/tihmstar/usbmuxd2) is written in C++ by tihmstar from the ground up to replace usbmuxd, but in my experience it segfaults easily.

[netmuxd](https://github.com/jkcoxson/netmuxd) is written in Rust by myself, but is largely untested because it's so new and does not support USB connected devices. It can act as an extension to vanilla usbmuxd, though.